# How to use ? syntax in Ruby while creating a String

Tags: ruby, syntax

While reading the documentation for `sort_by`, I came up with:

```
  files = Dir["*"]
  sorted = files.sort { |a, b|
    test(?M, a) <=> test(?M, b)
  }
  sorted   #=> ["mon", "tues", "wed", "thurs"]
```

As far as `?M` goes, it just creates a string `"M"`:

```
> ?\\
# => "\\"

> ?A
# => "A"

> ?1
# => "1"

> ?Hi!
SyntaxError ((irb):45: syntax error, unexpected '?')

> ?H 'i!'
# => "Hi!"
```

So what's the proper usage of the `?` syntax in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `?x` where x is any single character, will result to a single character string. `?x` is a shortcut for `'x'`. Try replacing `?M` with `'M'` in your code. It should have the same output.

```
files = Dir["*"]
sorted = files.sort { |a, b|
  test('M', a) <=> test('M', b)
}
sorted
```

Reference:

> There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding.
>
> https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/syntax/literals_rdoc.html

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-character-literals) discourages the use of the character literal syntax `?x`.